# Advanced query with MySQL Match Against

Tags: mysql, match-against

Is it possible using Match / Against to match a keyword, but not if it appears in a specific phrase?

For example, if I want to match "dog" but not "hot dog":

"This is a dog" should match.

"This is a hot dog" should not match.

"A hot dog is not a dog" should match because the second "dog" is not part of "hot dog".

My application searches for hundreds of keywords defined by the user in a large DB (~100K records), so performance of this query is important.

Edit:
I would like to match whole words only, not keywords which appear as part of another word.

Answer (score 1):

If you first `replace` all ocurences of `hot dog`with `''` and then carry out the `match` with `'dog'` on the result you should be getting there. Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE MATCH (REPLACE(mycol,'hot dog','')) AGAINST ('dog');
```

Just tried it out and `MATCH` seems to work differently. It requires a fulltext index to exist on the target columns and only they can be named as arguments of the `MATCH` function. Hence: **my approach does not work**. But what about

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REPLACE(mycol,'hot dog','') like '%dog%';
```

OK, then maybe this will help

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE REPLACE(mycol,'hot dog','') regexp '[[:<:]]dog[[:>:]]'
```

in finding only those cases where `'dog'` is a separate word?

Comment: Good idea, but I would like to match whole words (I should have mentioned that in the original question). With 'like' I will also get dog as part of another word.

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your solution but I think it is not completely user-proof: for example, if the user also wants "dog chain" and the text contains "hot dog chain". Also, I think the regexp performance will not scale well.